# Is it possible to implement [] myself and use it in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-management

To deepen my knowledge of I started attempting to create my own List class implementing from IEnumerable..

Looking at the List implementation I see that it is using T[], I was hoping that I would be able to implement my own version of the "[]", which would find available memory, see how much space my object takes up by adding up the sizes of the properties on the class i.e. 2 int properties (32 + 32 bits) and allocate this object to memory with a bit of extra space for other values like space for a pointer to the next location in memory for the next item..

Is this possible in C# or by using unmanaged code and creating a wrapper class to use it in C#?.. is this what "[]" is doing?.. I have searched online for implementing [] manually and cannot find any good resources, also browsing to the definition is not possible.. I have added c and c++ tags because it might be possible to create a solution in those languages and import the dll's for use in C#.. How could I implement this functionality and use it in C#?

Update:

The question is focused towards what are the options available in C# for implementing lower level functionality for example putting objects to and removing them from memory manually. For example not using the "[]" property given in C# but creating that functionality myself.. (Look at the implementation of List and how it uses []).. The reason I am wondering this is because I am exploring how low level C# lets us go to access memory ect.. What options do we have to do this, I've seen that there are windows api's (Win32 API's) maybe this is how to achieve this functionality or can this functionality be implemented in an unmanaged language and imported using dllimport, any advice on suggested approaches or further resources would be appreciated?

Comment: Line breaks and paragraphs are a beautiful thing.  Try some.

Comment: There are [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), but I am confused at what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: [] does NOT find/allocate memory. ... Within C#, there is the simple new and some other things, and in native binaries there´s much much more: Google.

Comment: @clcto I am trying to implement "[]" in code, to see how i can allocate objects to memory myself and if this is possible in C#.. or if i will have to implement this functionality by using an imported dll written in another language that is not in a memory managed environment so that I can implement this.

Comment: Allocating the memory is the easy bit, the hard part is making it work with the Garbage Collector.

Comment: Everything you've mentioned in your post is possible with C# (some with unsafe code), but it is not clear what exactly your are trying to achieve. Small sample code that show what you want to achieve and where you have problem would greatly improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways in .NET to allocate memory dynamically and to fill it up. You can use the `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` for instance to allocate unmanaged memory, and then you can fill the memory whatever way you like to. You need to be careful working between the managed and unmanaged world.

Comment: This answer addresses what I think the OP is actually asking: how to implement his own array-like type.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis thanks for your reply and i will check out the Marshal.AllocHGlobal(), i was also wondering what alternatives there are to implementing this functionality and using it in C#, i have found a windows api that looks like it has an api for accessing virtual memory.. Do you know if this is also a valid approach and also other valid approaches like a dll written in an unmanaged language C, C++ and dllimported into C#?

Comment: @DHavelock This isn't my answer and I don't know a lot about the subject, but I would *guess* that the Windows Virtual Memory Functions are probably the most obvious approach for allocating virtual memory and managing pages. But keep in mind that you'll be writing platform-specific code this way. There is no reason *not* to use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()`, in my opinion - it is the C# equivalent of `malloc`.

Comment: @DHavelock I agree with Theodoros Chatzigiannakis, if you use Windows API your code will be platform dependant. I suggest that you use the Marshal.AllocHGlobal().